Populating a column using sequence or other?
I'm trying to generate data for my graphics (cash flows, acquisition/churn rate etc..) and I'm having trouble with automating the formulas.
Here what I'm trying to do:
My game life as 3 main phase, prerelease, release, endoflife, I'm trying to generate the first 5 years, each phases has its own premise

prerelease: 5000 new users per month for 3 month, churn rate 50%
release: 100000 new users per month, churn rate 70%
end of life: 1000 new users per month, churn rate 90%

If I want to do projections on many years, is there a way to generate a column of values in one formula?
=sequence(nbmonthphase1, 1, 0, newusersphase1) + =sequence(nbmonthphase2, 1, 0, newusersphase2) + =sequence(nbmonthphase3, 1, 0, newusersphase3)

I played with =sequence(nbmonth, 1, 0, newusersphase1), etc., but didn't find a way to merge the 3 phases together.

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can Make an anonymous sample document

use only one =. the first one at the beginning.

sorry if its not clear, I added my case in the doc, its called "ŧests". https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pB42sssg_Q6TnVhRs458-nVx2aCpwP34czxFcGs_rDY/edit?usp=sharing. thank you for the support


You may try:
=tocol(reduce(,C5:C,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(offset(c,,-1)="value",sequence(offset(c,-1,),1,if(max(a)=0,0,max(a)+c),c),)))),1)



Wow thats next level! I'll have to make sure I understand to use it. Thank you!
